# How to make .i and .s file visible in a C project explorer?

Tags: c, makefile, eclipse-cdt

What are the instructions written inside the makefile of a C project to make both the expanded source code file .i and the assembly source code .s visible in the project explorer in eclipse IDE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that depends on the compiler. for `gcc` it is `-save-temps`

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen *[this site](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm)*?

Instructions for *[Showing or hiding files in the Project Explorer view](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm)*:

> You can choose to hide system files or generated class files in one of
>   the navigation views. (System files are those that have only a file
>   extension but no file name, for example .classpath.)
>
> ```
> On the toolbar for the Project Explorer, click the Menu button Menu button to open the drop-down menu of display options.
> Select Customize View..,.
> In the dialog box that opens, select the Filters tab and then select the checkboxes for the types of files that you want to hide.
> ```
>
> In addition, you can restrict the displayed files to a working set.
>
> ```
> On the toolbar for the Project Explorer, click the Menu button Menu button to open the drop-down menu of display options.
> Choose Select Working Set...
> Select an existing working set from the list or create a new one by selecting New...
> ```
>
> Related concepts

And there is also *[Searching for Files](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-48b.htm)*:

> Searching for files
>
> The Go To > Resource action in the Navigate menu allows you to quickly
>   find a resource in the Workbench by searching resource names.
>
> You can also do more complex searches for files in the Workbench. For
>   example, to find all files that end with .xml:
>
> ```
> On the main toolbar, click the command link Search button Search icon.
> Type *.xml into the File name patterns field and leave the Containing text field empty.
> (You can use the pull-down list to select *.xml if it had been previously entered.)
> Finish entering your search options, for example to scope the search to specified working sets, and click Search.
> The Search view displays the results of your search. Right-click on any item in the Search view to open a pop-up menu that allows you
> ```
>
> to remove items from the list, copy search results to the clipboard,
>   or rerun the search. To open one of the listed files, double-click it
>   or select Go to File from its pop-up menu.
>
> If you close the Search view, you can return to it later by selecting
>   command link Window > Show View > Other... > General > Search.

*(Replace *.xml with or *.i or *.s)*